# Issue with scroll on IOS using Safari

Tags: css, ios, safari

I have a problem when triggering a textarea. iOS allows me to scroll the screen to a height greater than the device, inserting undesirable space.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kRAZ.png)

I've already tried putting position: fixed and overflow: hidden and it didn't help.

Has anyone ever experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try Set the page height using (vh) and set dedicated height for the textarea itself.

Comment: I've also tried that and it didn't work. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).